# No data received on Datadog from Postman integration

Tags: postman, datadog

I want to create a monitor using Postman metrics. I installed the integration, but it is showing `no data received`.

[image: Postman integration on Datadog]

I have configured the integration properly and the Postman monitor is also running fine. I am not being able to find the problem. Because of this issue, I am not being able to access the Postman metrics.

P.S. I am using the free version of Postman.

[image: Postman monitor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other reasons. But free version does not allow you to send metrices.